# Environment variable cut off at the #

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04
```

I am trying to use my /etc/environment file, to export some variables, to be used by Rails.

```
cat /etc/environment

....
RAILS_ENV='test'
RAILS_DB_PWD='X35i#98n'
```

However, when I try:

```
echo $RAILS_DB_PWD
```

I get:

```
X35i
```

It looks like it's cut off at the #. I would like to include # in the password, and make it available system wide, not just from my local bash shell.

However, if I add this to my .bashrc file, it works fine

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/97736/180400

Comment: use `echo "$VAR"` instead. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

What does `shopt` show?

```
echo "${RAILS_DB_PWD}"
```

Should prevent the shell from interpreting the # that way.

Answer (score 0):

As Elias Soares said in his comment, /etc/environment is not a good place to set a variable with embedded `#`. Set it in your bash initialization file (for instance /etc/profile) as

```
RAILS_DB_PWD='X35i#98n'
```

and it should work. If you intend to span (non-bash) subshells or run programs you are supposed to use this environment variable, don't forget to export it.